# mql5 : OnCalculate close price difference of each bar Indicator

Tags: mql5

I'm pretty new to mql5 and are trying to create an indicator, what i want is simple, but i seem to be missing something from it.

I want to compare the close price of the 2 bars by the minute, if it is more than a certain value, it adds 1 to a indicator (Array?)

So Say

Bar A-1 closes at 1.555

Bar A closes at 1.455

each 0.01 it shall add 1 to the bar indicator, hence there should be a bar with a value of 10.

```html
#property copyright "Copyright 2011, MetaQuotes Software Corp." 
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com" 
#property version   "1.00" 
  
#property indicator_separate_window 
#property indicator_buffers 4 
#property indicator_plots   1 
//--- plot Bars 
#property indicator_label1  "Bars" 
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_BARS 
#property indicator_color1  clrGreen 
#property indicator_style1  STYLE_SOLID 
#property indicator_width1  5

#property indicator_maximum 5
#property indicator_minimum 0.000


//--- input parameter 
input int      pip=100;         // Number of pip  
//--- An indicator buffer for the plot 
double         LineBuffer[]; 

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
int OnInit() 
  { 
//--- Binding an array and an indicator buffer 
   SetIndexBuffer(1,LineBuffer,INDICATOR_DATA); 
//--- Initializing the generator of pseudo-random numbers 

//--- 
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED); 
  } 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total, 
                const int prev_calculated, 
                const datetime &time[], 
                const double &open[], 
                const double &high[], 
                const double &low[], 
                const double &close[], 
                const long &tick_volume[], 
                const long &volume[], 
                const int &spread[]) 
  { 

  
//--- Block for calculating indicator values 
   for(int i=0;i<rates_total;i++) 
     { 
      if(i>= 1 && (close[i] - close[i-1] >= pip*_Point))
      {
      LineBuffer[i]=1;
      }
     } 
  
//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return(rates_total); 
  }
```

yet when i tested it, it seem that close[i] is called every tick instead of every bar, and i can't seem to get the LineBuffer indicator to show the difference of close[i] and close[i-1] (hence i stuck it with 1 to get an indicator it has a difference more than the value called pip)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 4 buffers?

When calling `SetIndexBuffer', assign buffer id's one by one starting from zero.

Indeed, it is called every bar because you loop from bar#0 up to `rates_total`, if you need to call it once a bar, compare `prev_calculated' or use`datetime lastCandleClosed`and check whether`time[rates_total-1]>lastCandleClosed' to run a new bar logic.

By the way how you manages to call `close[i-1]` when `i=0`? You must have a critical error I suppose.

Comment: thanks, i'm still trying to understand the codes, so oncalculate calls every bar? or every tick? i actually editted this code from samples, i'm not sure what the buffer does.

Comment: `OnCalculate` is called every tick. There is no standard functions (neither in indicator or expert) to be called at start of the bar, you have to do that yourself. buffer keeps data of doubles for each bar on the chart